# language c - get few words with comma between

Tags: c

I would like to know how it's possible to do this :

I am actually doing some basic program, and the user has to enter something like this (via a scanf of course) :

word1,word2,word3

BUT I would like to get **each word in one variable**, that means without **,**. (But the user has to enter the ,).

So I want to get : $word1, $word2, ...

--

How is it possible ?

I can't use loop or complex functions of c (**it's forbidden by the exercise**). It has to be very basic.

Thanks by advance for help.. ;)

Comment: if loop cant be used, is the number of words tobe read is constant?

Comment: Yep, I just have 3 words to get ! (= The user has to write 3 words with comma between).

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know how to do this. I try with a simple scanf %s,%s,%s, but of course the commas were included in the string and this gave me an error :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there will always be only three words in the input, then yes can most definitely use [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), because it actually does simple pattern matching:

```
if (scanf("%[^ ,] , %[^ ,] , %[^ \n]", string1, string2, string3) == 3)
{
    /* Read three words */
}
```

If you can have a variable number of words, then read about [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Shouldn't you add something to the %s that disallows the comma?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer Joachim
But what does that mean /* Read three words */ ? I'm not sure to understand what I have to do here..

Comment: @LearningC Updated the format, should work better now.

Comment: @user3536493 The `scanf` call in my answer reads three "words", separated by comma, and puts them into the variables `string1`, `string2` and `string3`.

Comment: Ah I see that you changed %s to something else.

Ok, but what did you use if ?

scanf("%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", string1, string2, string3)

Enough no ?

Comment: @user3536493 What if the user inputs a malformed string? This way you can check for that. I also updated the format to skip whitespace between the strings and the commas (otherwise they are included in the strings).

Comment: Ah ok I get it now. I will test and see if it works with more than 3 words too. Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hum ok, there is a problem :

The user has to enter his 3 words two times before the program continue to run.. (But I wrote the scanf just one time of course). Like this :

`scanf("%[^ ,] , %[^ ,] , %[^ ,]", word1, word2, word3);`

Maybe I have to tell that I defined word1, 2 and 3 like this :

`char word1[10], word2[10], word3[10];`

Because after that, I have to see word1[4] word2[7].. (for example, that means to look at some letters of each words).

Comment: @user3536493 Ah, there was a slight error in my format, it didn't check for the trailing newline properly. Updated format in answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Great It works perfect ! Thanks a lot, because I did all the code for the next part of my prog but I was blocked here with this scanf with commas.

Do you know where I can find some explanations about this ? I mean how did you know that you have to write something like this : %[^ ,]

Comment: @user3536493 Follow the link in my answer, it leads to a reference where all formats are specified.