# scanf() for reading formatted input

Tags: c, scanf

I was trying get solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087380/language-c-get-few-words-with-comma-between#23087536) question.  I tried 
this code with gcc as the compiler and the output was not as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char s1[10],s2[10],s3[10];
    scanf("%s,%s,%s ",s1,s2,s3);
    printf("%s\n",s1);

}
```

Input

```
abc,def,ghi
```

Output

```
abc,def,ghi
```

I am printing only the string `s1` but it has the whole string.
Why doesn't `scanf()` read the input in such a way by breaking the input into 3 strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `scanf()` doesn't know that it should stop the first string conversion at the comma, since a string can contain the comma.

You can do this using the `%[]` conversion specifier, use `%[^,]` to include all characters except the comma.